# Does it make sense to create a separate index against a column, that is also a part of the composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I am using MySQL as my RDBMS.

But I think it must be applicable to other relational DBs.

I have a table Z, where I have 5 columns: a, b, c, d, e.

Columns a, b, c comprise a composite primary key.

Now, when it comes down to querying in the WHERE clause there will be times when I will be fetching data based on the values of columns a, b, c. But only one column out of 3 will be set.

Do I need to create 3 indices against these columns?

Follow-up question: what if I need to query my table knowing values for 2 columns out of 3? Will the creation of an additional 3 indices help to speed up my queries? (a, b) (a, c) (b, c)

Please advise.

Comment: Provide precise query text. Indices are NOT created "in general".

Comment: You can search on A based on the composite primary index.  B & C will possibly require additional indexes, but you would have to test to see if those indexes make a difference.  B, C would use the B index.  A, B or A, C would use the composite primary index.

Comment: A composite index can be used when searching/ordering any prefix of the key, so `(a, b, c)` will also act as an index on `(a, b)` and `(a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...will be fetching data based on the values of columns a, b, c. But only one column out of 3 will be set.

If that's the case you'll need three indexes:

- If `a` is set your primary key index `(a, b, c)` will suffice. You don't need to create an extra index for this case.
- If `b` is set you'll need the index `(b)` for this query to be fast.
- If `c` is set you'll need the index `(c)` for this query to be fast.

The index `(a, b, c)` is not useful when `a` is null. Remember, `null` is not a value.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

```
INDEX (a, b, c) 
-- creates 1 index of unique combinations of a&b&c, not unlike CONCAT(a, b,c)

INDEX (a),
INDEX (b),
INDEX (c)
-- creates 3 indexes of unique values for all a, b, c separately

INDEX (a, b),
INDEX (c)
-- creates 2 indexes:
--  1st for a&b unique values
--  2nd for c unique values
```

Follow up: with `WHERE a = '...' AND b = '...'`, searching thru `INDEX(a, b)` will be faster than searching thru `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)`. However, if `a` or `b` values are (at least mostly) unique, performance increase will not be significant.

When debugging index performance, always start witch checking your [indexes' cardinality](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-index-cardinality/) and later your queries' index usage with [`EXPLAIN SELECT`](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/).